# Absolute value of a complex exponential?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How do you take the absolute value of $e^{iaRe^{ix}}$ where a is a constant?

Apparently the answer is $e^{-aRsinx}$ but i have no clue how they got there :/

Comment: With the formula $\lvert e^z\rvert=e^{\Re z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$e^{iaRe^{ix}}=e^{iaR(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))}=$$

$$e^{iaR\cos(x)}e^{iaRi\sin(x)}=\underbrace{e^{iaR\cos(x)}}_{\text{form} \ e^{i\alpha}} \underbrace{e^{-aR\sin(x)}}_{r \in \mathbb{R}^+}$$

We find back in this way the polar form $re^{i\alpha}$ of a complex number, where $r$ is the modulus, or, as you call it, the absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What is the absolute value of $e^z$ where $z$ is a complex number? Does it help to express $z$ in terms of its real and imaginary parts?

Comment: ahh i see what you mean :)